# Prime Twelve Apostles

Tags: mathematics, optimization

You are given an empty square grid. Each cell can be an island with a positive integer $n$ or a bridge connecting islands. The following rules apply:

- Each island with a number $n$ must have exactly $n$ bridges attached to it
- Bridges must be either horizontal or vertical with one or more cells in length
- Bridges cannot intersect, but they can meet at an island
- All islands must be connected into a single component

For example, here is a valid arrangement for islands with numbers 1 to 4:

[image]

Can you find an arrangement for islands with numbers that are the first 12 odd primes: 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41? **Bonus:** what is the smallest rectangle (by area) that can fit such an arrangement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> These islands can be arranged in one line: numbers in brackets are the islands, number between dashes are the number of bridges between islands.
>
> ```
>  [3] -3- [5] -2- [7] -5- [11] -6- [13] -7- [17] -10- [23] -13- [37] -24- [41] -17- [29] -12- [31] -19- [19]
> ```

Comment: Great work, well done!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky is this the optimal area?

Comment: @newQOpenWid yes: it is the minimal number of cells: 12 islands + 11 bridges (which are necessary in order  that all the islands are connected)